# How to check whether a specific value exists or not in JSON string in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, json

I am having a JsonString as

```
[
  {
    "CountryId": "A26BF8CF-11A4-4A30-B47E-1CC0C3AC6D69",
    "CountryName": "Circuit_0",
    "Data": [
      {
        "SystemType": "Central",
        "SystemTypeId": "EF1FE7E8-6FF9-447E-9DAD-69D0EAAE0642",
        "ReferenceGuid": "04618DE5-B92B-41A3-B0EB-1EE8E4C329CC",
        "System": [
          {
            "System": "Bank",
            "SystemId": "3FC19ED5-A08C-4E2B-999C-37D6D83F7D65"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "IsCascade": false
   
  },
  {
    "CountryId": "4645CEE6-5061-4DB8-8E81-C7B1DB417E38",
    "CountryName": "Circuit_1",
    "Data": [
      {
        "SystemType": "State",
        "SystemTypeId": "94E1BEB7-BC8F-4D94-8027-3D53E6C9EB01",
        "ReferenceGuid": "289F5B6D-7CA1-422C-83D3-2688A88D18C5",
        "System": [
          {
            "System": "PF",
            "SystemId": "ADA9EBFA-DDCE-4CFA-9A07-10BCFD1232A3",
            "WinterTemp": "75"
          }
        ],
        "Cooling": "false"
      }
    ],
    "Total": "400"
  }
]
```

I want to check whether a SystemId= "3FC19ED5-A08C-4E2B-999C-37D6D83F7D65" exists or not. If exists i want to return true or else false

I tried using OPENJSON like below, but data is truncating.

```
DECLARE @Input NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[{"CountryId":"A26BF8CF-11A4-4A30-B47E-1CC0C3AC6D69","CountryName":"Circuit_0","Data":[{"SystemType":"Central","SystemTypeId":"EF1FE7E8-6FF9-447E-9DAD-69D0EAAE0642","ReferenceGuid":"04618DE5-B92B-41A3-B0EB-1EE8E4C329CC","System":[{"System":"Bank","SystemId":"3FC19ED5-A08C-4E2B-999C-37D6D83F7D65"}]}],"IsCascade":false},{"CountryId":"4645CEE6-5061-4DB8-8E81-C7B1DB417E38","CountryName":"Circuit_1","Data":[{"SystemType":"State","SystemTypeId":"94E1BEB7-BC8F-4D94-8027-3D53E6C9EB01","ReferenceGuid":"289F5B6D-7CA1-422C-83D3-2688A88D18C5","System":[{"System":"PF","SystemId":"ADA9EBFA-DDCE-4CFA-9A07-10BCFD1232A3","WinterTemp":"75"}],"Cooling":"false"}],"Total":"400"}]';
Select * from OPENJSON(
(Select Data from OPENJSON(@Input)
WITH (Data NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) 
for json path)) With (System NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON)
```

Could someone help me how to do this

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL is vendor specific.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have nested JSON, you need to extract those values in separate `OPENJSON` commands, which you can then `CROSS APPLY` to the original data. This query will give you all the `SystemId` values:

```sql
SELECT c.SystemId 
FROM OPENJSON(@Input)
WITH (Data NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.Data)
WITH (System NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) b
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.System) 
WITH (SystemId NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.SystemId') c
```

Output for your sample data:

```
SystemId
3FC19ED5-A08C-4E2B-999C-37D6D83F7D65
ADA9EBFA-DDCE-4CFA-9A07-10BCFD1232A3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/SEq85R_7)

To get a true/false indication as to whether a value exists, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c.SystemId = N'3FC19ED5-A08C-4E2B-999C-37D6D83F7D65' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IdExists
FROM OPENJSON(@Input)
WITH (Data NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.Data)
WITH (System NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) b
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.System) 
WITH (SystemId NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.SystemId') c
```

Output for your sample data:

```
IdExists
1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/3tYFyJGb)

If you're getting your data from another query, you can use it as a subquery in either the `OPENJSON` or the `FROM` clause. For example:

```sql
SELECT c.SystemId 
FROM OPENJSON((SELECT TOP 1 JsonColumnString FROM test))
WITH (Data NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.Data)
WITH (System NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) b
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.System) 
WITH (SystemId NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.SystemId') c
```

or

```sql
SELECT c.SystemId 
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 JsonColumnString FROM test) t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JsonColumnString)
WITH (Data NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.Data)
WITH (System NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) b
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.System) 
WITH (SystemId NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.SystemId') c
```

[Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/-x2MZPry)

Comment: I am getting the @Input from a query like this: 
```
Select top 1 JsonColumnString from TableName 
    where CountryId = (Select top 1 CountryId from Globe where GlobeId='9abbeecf-15a4-412f-ba0c-358b8f09ac9e')
for json path
```
When I replace @Input with this Query I am getting NULL as output.

Comment: @Avinash this is why it's important to ask a question with your actual environment, not something you made up. Did you remember to put the query in `()` (all subqueries must be parenthesized i.e. `OPENJSON(( Select top 1 JsonColumnString ... ))`?

Comment: @Avinash please see my edit and new demo, hopefully that will guide you...

Comment: It's working now. thanks for the quick information and explained in a understandable manner

Comment: @Avinash good to hear! I'm glad I could help